# Make mullti-type container in c++ (map)

Tags: c++, c++17, decltype

In java this code works pretty good:

```
static void f(){
    HashMap hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("string", 1234);
    hm.put(2134, "string");
    System.out.println(hm.get(2134));
    System.out.println(hm.get("string"));
}
```

can i make this feature in c++? (maybe decltype hash and 3-dimensional container??)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Variant class and std::map<Variant, Variant>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868341/creating-a-variant-class-and-stdmapvariant-variant)

Comment: In Java everything inherits from Object, which has equals() and hashCode() methods. You'll need to implement those somehow for a hash map, or the `<` operator in order to use a binary tree.